# How to perform an action before user reload page or exit my vuejs application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, buefy

So, I'm using the version 2.6.11 and I'm facing some difficulties to perform an action before the user exit my application or reloads the page.

I'm doing a integration of a CRM with telephony. When the user access my application he needs to login (not in my application, but in a hub that I'm accessing with SignalR), so I can perform some action like make a call, receive a call, and handle the events that I receive from the hub. The problem is: if the user reloads the page or exit the page, I need to log him out of the hub connection.

When using angular the solution was very simple, i just needed to call:

```js
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    // Log user out here
});
```

... but I can't do this with vue. I've been trying to use the `beforeDestroy`, `keep-alive`, `destroyed`, and other methods, but none of them are helping me to achieve my goal. I tried pure javascript like:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => { 
    // Log user out here
}
```

... but for some reason not even this had helped me to solve the issue.

I really don't know if it is my mistake, or if this is not implemented on vue yet, but I haven't find similar issues on internet. Is there any solution inside the framework, or anything I can do with javascript to perform an action before the user exit or reload the page?

Comment: What're you trying to do in the `beforeunload` handler? Are you making a call to an endpoint?

Comment: Kinda like vue Lifecycle Hooks don't have onbeforeunload api https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks

Comment: Maybe `navigator.sendBeacon(url, data);` help you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: @Terry I'm sending a command to the hub, to finish the connection

Comment: "Sending a command", but how? By dispatching an AJAX request? Or by invoking a function?

Comment: @Terry I'm using JQuery to call a method inside the hub:

`$.connection.atendimentoHub.server.terminar()`

Comment: @eli vue doesn't have it but javascript have this event https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp , so I thought it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem. I was putting the `onbeforeunload` event in the wrong place. And, in my case, the `onbeforeunload` wasn't the answer. To log out the user I just needed to call:

```js
import { EventBus } from "@/services/eventBus"

window.onunload = function () {
    EventBus.$emit("onunload")
}
```

... in `main.js`. Then, I was able to listen to this event and call a function in the `.vue` file:

```js
mounted() {
    EventBus.$on("onunload", this.logout);
},
```